# jQuery page transition makes previous page blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition

I'm using the following script with jQuery to have a fade transition when navigating between pages:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(200);
    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(200, redirectPage);
    });
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

It works fine when only using links to navigate between pages, but when using the back button on the browser, the page returned to is blank.

How can I get pages to be properly displayed when navigating to them via the back button?

Comment: How about using delegate, i.e. .on('click', function(){})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the back button returns you to the state of the previous page right before you left it (in this case, completely faded out), at least that's how I understand it. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong though.

In any case, I think repainting the DOM would solve your problem (taken from [Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/ahazha/force-redraw-on-an-element-jquery)):

```
$.fn.redraw = function(){
    $(document).each(function(){
        var redraw = this.offsetHeight;
    });
};
```

And to call the function: `$(document).redraw();`

Comment: Sorry, there was a `$(document).ready()` I forgot to include it. Updated the question, thanks.

Comment: @jla Ah, ok. I changed my answer to something I think may be the problem.

Comment: Repainting worked like a dream. I also set an empty function to be called on window.onunload to make sure the script was being run. Works perfectly now, cheers :)

Comment: @jla Sweet, glad I could help (:

Answer (score 0):

How about try using delegate

```
$("a").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("body").fadeOut(200, redirectPage);
});
```